Manage scanned barcode with GmsBarcodeScanning
I have a fragment with an EditText and a couple of buttons.
One of the buttons allows the user to scan a barcode with the GmsBarcodeScanning library.
If successful, the scanned barcode shoould appear into the EditText, but I can't get it to work.
The problem seems to be that after the onSuccessListener() the onCreateView() is executed and thus all the components are reset.
I think it must be simple, but I've spent hours and can't find a solution.
class SelecComanda : Fragment() {
private var et_codi: EditText? = null
private var btn_scan: Button? = null
private var btn_next: Button? = null

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selec_comanda, container, false)
    et_codi = root.findViewById(R.id.editTextCodi)
    btn_scan = root.findViewById(R.id.boto_scan)
    btn_next = root.findViewById(R.id.button_second)
    return root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    btn_next!!.isEnabled = false

    btn_next!!.setOnClickListener {
        // TODO
    }

    btn_scan!!.setOnClickListener {
        val options = GmsBarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
            .enableAutoZoom()
            .build()
        val scanner = GmsBarcodeScanning.getClient(this.context!!, options)

        scanner.startScan()
            .addOnSuccessListener { barcode ->
                et_codi!!.setText(barcode.rawValue.toString())
                btn_next!!.setEnabled(true)
        }
        .addOnCanceledListener {
            // TODO
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            // TODO
        }
    }
}

}
How could I recover the scanned barcode and put into the EditText?

is barcode.rawValue.toString() even returning non empty string?

Can you try below code
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val gmsScannerOptions = configureScannerOption()
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val instance = getBarcodeScannerInstance(gmsScannerOptions)
    btn_scan!!.setOnClickListener {
        initiateScanner(instance)
    }
}

private fun configureScannerOption(): GmsBarcodeScannerOptions {
    return GmsBarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
        .setBarcodeFormats(
            Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE,
            Barcode.FORMAT_AZTEC
        )
        .build()
}

private fun getBarcodeScannerInstance(gmsBarcodeScannerOptions: GmsBarcodeScannerOptions): GmsBarcodeScanner {
    return GmsBarcodeScanning.getClient(this, gmsBarcodeScannerOptions)
// Or with a configured options
// val scanner = GmsBarcodeScanning.getClient(this, options)
}

private fun initiateScanner(gmsBarcodeScanner: GmsBarcodeScanner) {
    gmsBarcodeScanner.startScan()
        .addOnSuccessListener { barcode ->
            // Task completed successfully
            val result = barcode.rawValue
            Log.d(TAG, "initiateScanner: $result")

            when (barcode.valueType) {
                Barcode.TYPE_URL -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "initiateScanner: ${barcode.valueType}")
                }

                else -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "initiateScanner: ${barcode.valueType}")
                }
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "initiateScanner: Display value ${barcode.displayValue}")
            Log.d(TAG, "initiateScanner: Display value ${barcode.format}")
        }
        .addOnCanceledListener {
            // Task canceled
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            // Task failed with an exception
        }
}

